# Getting "wrong parameter count..." error with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have been trying to learn prepared statements so that we can start implementing them thoughout our PHP sites. This function takes values (or none) from text boxes on a search form using the $_POST transfer method then uses the names and values of those textboxes to add criteria to the WHERE clause. The function worked previously ut I can't seem to get the prepared statement to function.

Researching several scripts I started using the one below and worked out a few bugs. now when I run it I get the error **Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param()**

After this query runs I want to export the values into a table and was working before attempting the prepared statement.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
  <?php

   $db = mysqli_connec("ip_address", "loginname", "password", "database");

    $refs = array('sssss');

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
     {
       $refs[] =& $_POST[$key];
      }    

$query = "SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 FROM tbl_name WHERE 1=1";
    foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) 
    { 
      if(!empty($v)) {
        $query .= " AND $k = ?"; 
        $params[$k] = $v;
        }   
    }       

    $results = $db->prepare($query);        

     call_user_func_array(array($results, 'bind_param'), $refs);

    $results->execute();
```

?>

Comment: Turn on error reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the way I solved this was to scrap everything and start over, which is always fun...but the new script that works for what I need is here

```
<?php


$dbhost     = "ip_address";
$dbname     = "db_name";
$dbuser     = "db_login";
$dbpass     = "db_pass"; 

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE 1=1";

    foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) 
    { 
      if(!empty($v)) {
        $query .= " AND $k LIKE ?";
        $params[] = $v;     
      }  
    }   

    $results = $conn->prepare($query);  
    $results->execute($params);

    $results->bindColumn(1, $no);
    $results->bindColumn(2, $date);
    $results->bindColumn(3, $name);
    $results->bindColumn(4, $id);
    $results->bindColumn(5, $path);

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Parameters passed to [`mysqli_stmt::bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) must be passed by reference, and only variables can be passed by reference, so you cannot pass the result of a function directly into `call_user_func_array` in this case. Also, the first parameter passed to `bind_param` is a string list of the variable types. Instead, try this:

```
// Change to whatever types are relevant
$refs = array('sss');

foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
  $refs[] =& $arr[$key];
}

call_user_func_array(array($results, 'bind_param'), $refs);
```

**Edit**

This line is wrong:

```
$results = $mysqli->prepare($query);
```

Should be

```
$results = $db->prepare($query);
```

Comment: Thanks Michael but still having the same problem

Comment: Have you seen my edit? You don't have a `$mysqli` variable; you have a `$db` variable.

Comment: Do `print_r` on `$results`. It might be that your query is failing and so that is returning `FALSE` rather than a `mysqli_stmt` object (and so use `$db->error` to get the error).

Comment: Not getting anything on either of thoses. Its like the script stops when It gets to the $results declaraton This error is getting my attention: call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'Array' was given

Comment: Try `var_dump`, then. `print_r` wouldn't show anything if `FALSE`.

Comment: var_dump($results) = bool(false) ---- var_dump($db->error) = string(0) ""

Comment: There's something wrong with your query. `echo $query` and see if there's anything wrong.

Comment: The above issues have been corrected. Now getting "Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param" ... updated code in original question

Comment: See the first part of my answer about how to use `call_user_func_array` with `bind_param`. Obviously as the comment says you'll need to change `$refs = array('sss');` to match the number and type of parameters you're passing.

Comment: Updated my code above to show you what I have. Tried your suggestion the other day got this "Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [function.mysqli-stmt-bind-param]: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in /path/

Comment: That would mean that there are more or less than 5 `$_POST` values. What is `count($_POST)`?

Comment: Thank you! The `&` sign was what I was missing. Line `$refs[] =& $arr[$key];` saved me.